# Pass YES and NO sequentially to a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I need to pass yes or no input to a bash script. It works for single single input using `yes`, however if the bash script has multiple input (more than one) how can I pass it ? Below is the example for a single yes input:

```
yes | ./script
```

I can't send as below if the script needs different input, for instance:

```
yes | no | ./script
```

Answer (score 5):

`yes` sends `y` (or whatever else you tell it to send) to its standard output. If you want `yes` and `no` on the standard output, you can use `echo`:

```
{   echo yes
    echo no
} | ./script
```

I used a block to pipe both inputs to the script. There are more possible ways, e.g.

```
printf '%s\n' yes no | ./script.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass 1 *`yes`*, then 1 *`no`*, then again 1 *`yes`* and 1 *`no`* and so on by using:

```
yes $'yes\nno' | ./script.sh
```

Using bash, you could revert pipe by using this syntaxe:

```
./script < <(yes $'yes\nno')
```

Sample:

```
head -n 6 < <(yes $'yes\nno')
yes
no
yes
no
yes
no
```

... or two *`yes`* and one *`no`*:

```
head -n 6 < <(yes $'yes\nyes\nno')
yes
yes
no
yes
yes
no
```

Or any other combination...

Answer (score 2):

We can also use below command also

```
echo -e "yes\nno" | ./script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just send the lines you want -

```
printf "yes\nno\n" | ./script.sh
```

or if you need a certain number of each -

```
{ yes yes |head -50; yes no | head -50; } | ./script.sh
```

Or if you need them toggled -

```
yes | awk '{ if (NR%2) {print "yes"} else {print "no"} }' | ./script.sh
```

(only using `yes` here as a driver for records to read, lol)

Comment: I like F. Hauri's better. :)